# How one service (not singleton) can be used by one directive and one component?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I have created a directive that is using component as its template. Both of them use the same service included in providers:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  providers: [MyService],
  ..
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]',
  providers: [MyService]
})
```

Now here is the problem. They use the same service, but while one is changing the server, the directive that has been register to its change didn't got the change at all:

```
this.myService.dataUpdated.subscribe
      (
        (data: someObject) => {
          // Do something...
        }
      )
```

Seems to me they are not using the same service at all.

Comment: That's why the service must be a singleton.

Comment: Remove one of them

Comment: If I remove one of them, for example from the component, How the component may change that service so the directive will be notified about that change?

Comment: Please create plunker. We need more information about their relations

Comment: Here is my example https://plnkr.co/edit/kXdKeaZOZOVfP18tLvfO?p=preview Just click on title and you will see that they are using the same instance of service

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why singleton should not be used for your scenario. It seems to me that singleton should be used on your case, that's why you don't see the changes at all.

Try to provide your service in your NgModule like this

```
 @NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [MyService]
  ...
```

Hope this helps.